# Update nuget package referenced by package

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2017

I have a nuget-package *A* in my project that uses nuget-package *B*.

When I update package *B* I alway have to update the nuget-package-rerefence to *B* in nuget-package *A* and then update the nuget-package-reference to *A* in my project.

Is there any way to directly update the implicitly referenced nuget-package *B* in my top-level-project?

Comment: Confirm, is package A and package B separate packages? And nuget package B is dependence of nuget package A?

Comment: A and B are separate packages built from separate solutions. Package a uses package B. And the top-level-project uses package A (and hence package B implicitly).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to directly update the implicitly referenced nuget-package B in my top-level-project?

Sure, just add a direct dependency from your project to package B - then you can specify the version you want.

When package A is updated so that it now refers to the same version of B as you want, you can remove the direct dependency again.

Comment: Is there no other way? I don't want to add all the tier-2 and tier-3 packages to the solution (there are about 100 in total).

Comment: @user2033412: I don't know what you mean by "tier-2 and tier-3 packages" - but the only packages you need to add directly are the ones you want to change the version of. If there are 100 packages that you want to change the version of, that sounds like a bigger problem...

Comment: I'm talking about packages that are referenced by packages.

Comment: @user2033412: But you don't need to add those, and I never said you did. You only need to add the packages where you want to explicitly specify the version numbers. So in the example you gave in the question, you add a dependency on B. You don't need to add a dependency on anything that B refers to.

Comment: My Problem is: There are a dozend projects depending on A. And they all want B1 to B4 to be in the current version. I can of course add all these packages. But it would be nicer if package A could define: "Give me the latest Version of package B" and the nuget-updates would show this update (without explicitly adding it).

Comment: @user2033412: You could always create a dependencies-only package A2 that depended on B1-B4 and was easier to update than A. Then you just need to update *that* each time B1-B4 change. Alternatively, you can add dependencies on B1-B4 (to each of the packages - yes, there are dozens, but that's a one-time hit) that don't specify a version, and then they'll always be updated, as I understand it. (It doesn't help that we don't know whether you're using packages.config or the newer SDK projects.)